# access Adobe Printing Preferences output folder

Tags: c#, printing, adobe

I want to programmatically access Adobe's default print folder location if such is set. Is there a way to do that with C#?

I think I will be fine with just knowing what its set to, but if its possible to set this setting from my app, then that would be great too.

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean navigating to your personal Documents folder? assuming you are using the default paths, that's C:\users\<yourUsername>\documents

Comment: No, I don't mean to navigate to MyDocuments folder...obviously you can set that to a custom location. I need to obtain that path regardless to what its set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sorry, but I don't think that's possible.

> You cannot directly set any of these options (in any case, print driver options are very problematic as they are handled by a level of indirection in Windows and the registry keys can vary).

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1079735

Comment: If your answer has a link to an article that would be great only if you put the piece used for answer in quote here.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the settings in that dialog box live in the registry at:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\Adobe PDF`
and 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\Adobe PDF\PrinterDriverData`

Specifically, the "Port" key which has `Documents\*.pdf` is the one you want.

*Note: Since these are HKLM keys, they will require administrator rights to change*

Comment: This is invalid for Windows 10 Enterprise / Adobe Acrobat XI pro. The registry key remains Documents\*.pdf even if you set the output folder to be something different.